# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, navigationview

**Ever since i upgraded my android studio to version 3.5.1, i have been trying to use NagigationView, but keeps crashing my app, any help will b really welcomed**

````
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>```
````

Comment: Can you post your logcat too see the errors please

Comment: Also which app theme are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/452